# How to delete a limited number of rows in Apache Derby

Tags: sql, database, limit, derby, sql-delete

I want to delete a certain number of obsolete rows from a table in Derby. Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE obsolete = 1 LIMIT 100000;
```

But Derby doesn't support the non-standard LIMIT syntax. Unfortunately the usual replacement does not work either:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE obsolete = 1 FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY;
```

While the following eventually works, performance is awful:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE obsolete = 1 FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY);
```

And iterating over a ResultSet calling .deleteRow() repeatedly terminates after visiting a few more than 64K rows, with no indication that anything went wrong, the cursor just stops returning rows as if there weren't any left.

Is there a better way to delete a large number, but not all, of the rows in a table?

Comment: Are there any keys, such as timestamps, that can be used to filter the delete?

Comment: I have tried to filter the delete with a date column, but I can't predict how many rows are associated with any particular span of time. It is important that I not try to delete too many rows at once.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a suggestion. Try adding an index on `(obsolete, id)` and then run this variation (and perhaps experimenting with smaller than `100000` number:

```
DELETE 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN 
      ( SELECT id 
        FROM table 
        WHERE obsolete = 1
        ORDER BY id 
        FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY
      )
```

The idea is to use the index to get the ids and not scan the whole table every time the statement is executed.